# Bind List<class> to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I need your help on how to bind List to the DataGridView. I tried to use the `BindingList<T>` but still it does not display the records in my gridview. I tried using the `List<T>`, but it still does not work.

Below is the code which I used:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolClientController ctrl = new ToolClientController();
        IpAddressTextbox.Text = ctrl.GetIPv4Config();
        PortNumberTextbox.Text = ctrl.GetPortNumber();
    }

    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ToolMsgFileTextbox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ToolMsgFileTextbox.Text))
        {
            FileTypeError.SetError(UploadButton, "Please enter filename.");
            return;
        }

        if (!openFileDialog1.FileName.Contains(".txt"))
        {
            FileTypeError.SetError(UploadButton, "File should be in .txt");
            return;
        }

        ToolClientController ctrl = new ToolClientController();            

        List<ToolMessages> test = new List<ToolMessages>();
        ToolMessages tool = new ToolMessages();
        tool.IsPass = true;
        tool.ToolMessageReply = string.Empty;
        tool.ToolMessageRequest = "x";
        test.Add(tool);

        MessageGridViews.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col1.DataPropertyName = "ToolMessageRequest";
        col1.HeaderText = "Request";            
        MessageGridViews.Columns.Add(col1);

        BindingList<ToolMessages> bind = new BindingList<ToolMessages>(test);

        MessageGridViews.VirtualMode = true;
        MessageGridViews.DataSource = bind; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you click `UploadButton` and you are not seeing the output as in my answer below, i.e. column "Request" wih value "x" ? Also, what for are you creating `ToolClientController` in `UploadButton_Click` if you are not using it at all? On different note, have you tried placing breakpoint into `UploadButton_Click` method to actually see what happens? Whether your code gets executed at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I prepared simple WinForms app:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<ToolMessages> test = new List<ToolMessages>();
    ToolMessages tool = new ToolMessages();
    tool.IsPass = true;
    tool.ToolMessageReply = string.Empty;
    tool.ToolMessageRequest = "x";
    test.Add(tool);

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    col1.DataPropertyName = "ToolMessageRequest";
    col1.HeaderText = "Request";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);

    BindingList<ToolMessages> bind = new BindingList<ToolMessages>(test);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bind;
    dataGridView1.Show();
}
```

I added `dataGridView1` into form directly via WinForms designer, so `InitializeComponent` method looks like:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // dataGridView1
    // 
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(560, 57);
    this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
    this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
    this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(967, 399);
    this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridControl1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gridView1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

And everything seems to work just fine... Data are bound to grid and ouput looks like:
[image]

which is exactly what I would expect to see, so I don't see any real problem with you solution, unless you post bigger piece of your code on which I can reproduce the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I'll edit my question because I still cannot get the records to display.

Comment: I just found out that my entity had caused the problem. I set the `[Browsable(true)]` and it worked.